# Unity 3D: Vertical Layout Group not placing elements where they should be

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am having a problem with my layout groups and keeping my UI consistent. I have a menu that holds two empty elements Blue and Green boxes bellow that get filled at playtime depending on what the player does. The orange boxes are buttons that may add or remove both purple boxes or orange boxes depending on the button pressed. The Gray, Blue, and Green boxes all have Vertical Layout Group and Content Size fitter (vertical fit set to "Prefered Size"). So from my understanding, all children within these boxes should be stacked vertically and will expand and contract the box as needed.

The problem I am having is that the first time I press a button that adds a purple box and expands the blue box, the green box stays where it is. The second time I press a button the Green box shifts where it should be no matter what gets added to the blue box. Conversely if pressing a button for the first time removes purple boxes and contracts the blue box, the green box stays where it is until I press a button again then shifts where it should be.

[image]

If I manually change any of the Gray, Blue, or Green boxes attributes such as anchor pivot or scale the boxes rearrange themselves the way it should be.

Am I doing something wrong with Vertical Layout / Content Size fitter? I hope this is enough to go on. I can provide code if need be. I just don't know exactly what to share.

When the button is pressed call this method.

```
void AcceptUnlockButtonInput(Exit roomExit) {
    if (PlayerHasKeyForExit(roomExit)) {
        LogAction(roomExit.exitUnlockDescription);
        roomExit.attemptedToExit = false;
        roomExit.attemptedToUnlock = false;
    } else if (roomExit.attemptedToUnlock == false) {
        LogAction(roomExit.exitLockedDescription);
    }

    DisplayActionText();

    foreach(Transform child in inputContainer.transform) {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }

    DisplayInputButtons();
    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
}
```

`LogActrion()` just simply adds a string to a list then `DisplayActionTest()` reads off that list and creats/adds gameObjects to the container.

```
public void DisplayActionText() {
    actionLog.ForEach(value => {
        var textObject = Instantiate(displayTextPrefab) as GameObject;
        var textMeshPro = textObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        textMeshPro.text = value;
        textObject.transform.SetParent(outputContainer.transform, false);
    });

    actionLog.Clear();
    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
}
```

Simply creats a button for each exit and adds the original method to the buttons listener.

```
public void DisplayInputButtons() {
    foreach (var exit in Exits) {
            var unlockButton = Instantiate(userActionButton) as GameObject;
            newButton.text = buttonText;
            newButton.transform.SetParent(buttonGroup.transform, false);
            unlockButton.onClick.AddListener(() => AcceptUnlockButtonInput(exit));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem with layout groups. From my understanding, layout groups don't update immediately when you put something in them.

Something what worked for me was:

`LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(recttransform of the layoutgroup);`

You can also try disabling and enabling the layout group component:

```
IEnumerator UpdateLayoutGroup()
{
layoutGroupComponent.enabled = false;
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
layoutGroupComponent.enabled = true;
}
```

If enabling and disabling the layoutgroup component doesn't work you can also try this:

```
IEnumerator UpdateLayoutGroup()
{
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

layoutGroupComponent.enabled = false;

layoutGroupComponent.CalculateLayoutInputVertical();

LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(recttransform of the layoutgroup);

layoutGroupComponent.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions seems to work. Even when substituting the right method calls. 

`this.inputContainer.SetActive(true or false);`

`this.inputContainer.gameObject.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().CalculateLayoutInputVertical();`

        `LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(this.inputContainer.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>());`

Unless those are the wrong methods and I should be using something else.

Answer (score 4):

**Update answer**

In my case there were multiple layout groups nested into each other, so the rebuild of the parent layout group did not work. In the first try I rebuild all in hierarchy (old answer), but ran into performance issues for large lists. Then I found a much more robust and performant way (with help from [Answer from Adam-Buckner](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1202057/view.html) and [Auto-Layout Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIAutoLayout.html)):

1. Only the topmost layout group of the layout group hierarchy has a content size fitter, any descendant must not have one
2. All vertical layout groups have checked Control Child Size (Width & Height), Use Child Scale (Only Height), Child Force Expand (Only Width)
3. When the layout is being affected by code, due to adding/removing elements or setting a component active, I use the following code (it uses MarkLayoutForRebuild, which prevents recomputing a node multiple times)

(starting from element with changes, first line can be omitted if element is not a LayoutGroupon its own)

```
LayoutRebuilder.MarkLayoutForRebuild((RectTransform)transform);
LayoutGroup[] parentLayoutGroups = gameObject.GetComponentsInParent<LayoutGroup>();
foreach (LayoutGroup group in parentLayoutGroups) {
  LayoutRebuilder.MarkLayoutForRebuild((RectTransform)group.transform);
}
```

It works really well and I have no longer elements jumping around. As far as I understand content size fitters control a RectTransform, but competes with the parent LayoutGroup which also want to control it (therefore the warning in the editor). If only LayoutGroups are nested into each other, the algorithm can easily compute the sizes from bottom up, so the bottom most layout groups derive their size from their children (Caused by Use Child Scale), which is then applied to it by their parent layout group (caused by Control Child Size). LayoutGroups does not affect the RectTransform of the element it is placed on, only on its children. Finally the top element gets a height from the hierarchy which is then applied to itself the content size fitter.

**Old and inefficient answer**

In my case there were multiple layout groups nested into each other, so the rebuild of the parent layout group did not work. I had to rebuild all in hierarchy, to properly update the layout.

```
LayoutGroup[] parentLayoutGroups = gameObject.GetComponentsInParent<LayoutGroup>();
foreach (LayoutGroup group in parentLayoutGroups) {
  LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate((RectTransform)group.transform);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I have not tested it but it looks like I would work.

Comment: Can confirm! For me, this worked perfectly without any need to force updates via code. First, there really should only be a content-size-fitter on the topmost layout group, and secondly the mentioned checkmarks needed to be set, though not necessarily all. F.e. "child force expand width" was not necessary on the layout groups that were lower in the hierarchy.
For me yours is the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar problems and I found this to be helpful: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases.html

Sometimes when instantiating elements into a gameobject with a vertical layout group, the elements will only get into their right position after updating the canvas.

Comment: This works but it juggles the container a bit after I press the button. It should be fine in most situations but it looks a bit odd.

Comment: What do you mean with "juggles"? Could you perhaps make a small recording of what happens when you press the button? 
(I use a program called "ShareX" to record my screen and I upload to a website called "streamable" to make small recordings like these to show to colleagues)

Comment: oops, I meant to type jiggles. https://streamable.com/u4m9j near the end when I press unlock a few times the button group moves down slightly and then snaps back up. This may not be a problem. I am working on making the button disabled if you don't have the keys to unlock the exit. But I don't know if this is the only place that the UI jiggles now.

Comment: Strange! Could you elaborate on what happens in the script when you press the button?

Comment: There you go I edited my question with some code. I tried to condense it as much as possible for you.

Comment: I am not sure if my assumption is correct, but it looks like you instantiate something and then delete it again when pressing that unlock button? I think it might jiggle because you forceupdate inbetween too?

Comment: That might be true. I can take a look into that. The is for the help.

Comment: this worked for me, whereas the MarkLayoutForRebuild answer unfortunately didn't

Answer (score 1):

I know there is an issue with the VLG not updating correctly. Changing any of its value after adding/ removing elements forces its layout to resize and may fix your issue (at least that's the way I do it).

Can you try :
- Add/remove your element
- VerticalLayoutLement.spacing += Random.Range(-1,1);

To be sure it rescales properly i usually do it in a coroutine with an"yield return new WaitForNewFrame()" before the spacing part.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that but my efforts did not seem to work. I thought about changing the scale on the Z-axis as that does not affect my UI and it fixes the problem when I do it manually. I just feel as though it is a slopy fix. But if it works it works.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of tricks that I found on the web I felt a little frustrated because none of them worked for me. When I ran the scene all the elements in the vertical layout looked messed, but when I clicked on Pause and Continue they magically fitted perfectly in the right position, so I wrote this simple funcion to emulate it, that works fine in my app:

```
IEnumerator RefreshPrefab(GameObject prefabInstance)
{
    prefabInstance.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    prefabInstance.SetActive(true);
}
```

And call it sending as parameter the parent prefab that contains the layout group:

```
StartCoroutine(RefreshPrefab(instantiatedPrefab));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here is an example with three methods.

You can choose the best one.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Method one, Worked on most cases.
    /// </summary>
    private void RefreshLayoutByMethodOne()
    {
        Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
        transform.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>().enabled = false;
        transform.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>().enabled = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method two, Worked, but here is one frame shake.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator RefreshLayoutByMethodTwo()
    {
        transform.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>().enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        transform.GetComponent<LayoutGroup>().enabled = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method three, Worked
    /// </summary>
    private void RefreshLayoutByMethodThree()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
            LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<RectTransform>());
        // Call on every game object whose transform changed.
        // LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call any of three.
    /// </summary>
    private void DoRefreshLayout()
    {
        RefreshLayoutByMethodOne();
        StartCoroutine(RefreshLayoutByMethodTwo());
        RefreshLayoutByMethodThree();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I still on occasion have issues with this. Its mostly fixed but there sometimes is a noticeable delay.

Answer (score -1):

LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(rectTransform>);

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide more information than the existing answers, I think you should read the [help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons leading to answer deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).